# Unable to update MVC3 Model - InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am fairly new to prgramming in general. I have a database with 3 tables in it. A table called `User` with a foreign Key `TypeID` null, a table called `Login` that has a foreign key `UserID` null and `TypeID` not null, and a table called `Types` with `TypeID` as the primary key. When I tried to update my entity Model, I receive an `Invalid InvalidOperationException`.

```
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Object entity, EntityState entityState)
at MBMVCApplication.Controllers.LoginController.Edit(Users user, Int32 TypeID) in C:\Development\MBMVCApplication\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 130
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

**Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Login login, int? typeID)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Logins.Attach(login);
        //TypeID display on a dropdown box
        //I also remove the two line below and still get the error
        login.User.TypeID = typeId.Value;
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(login, EntityState.Modified); //The error occurs here or 
        db.SaveChanges(); //Here
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserID", "FirstName", login.UserID);
    ViewBag.TypeID= new SelectList(db.Types, "TypeID", "Description", login.TypeID);

    return View(login);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to manually updated each table. I ran a query to obtain the primary ID; then, I created a new object for the model passing all the values that were selected from the view and updated the table using the primary key. Any table that had a foreign key associated with that table had to be updated manually. It was time consuming and may not be efficient, but it happens to be the workaround.

Comment: We like full answers here - see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).